# Using bootstrap-tour with Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, bootstrap-tour

I have not been able to find a good example of how to use [Bootstrap Tour](https://bootstraptour.com/) with Aurelia.  I installed it with yarn (`yarn add bootstrap-tour`) and added the dependencies in `main.js` as follows:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-tour/build/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import 'bootstrap-tour/build/js/bootstrap-tour.min.js';
```

Now I would like to use it in one of my view-models.  Here is what I've tried:

```
import { Tour } from 'bootstrap-tour';
```

In my class definition:

```
@inject(Store, EventAggregator, I18N, Router, Tour)
export default class {
  constructor(store, events, i18n, router, tour) {
    this.store = store;
    this.events = events;
    this.i18n = i18n;
    this.router = router;
    this.tour = tour;
  }

  // ... other methods and code

  startTour() {
    const tourNewReports = new this.tour({
      steps: [
        {
          element: '#tour-btn-menu',
          title: 'New reports!',
          content: 'Check out new reports!',
        },
        {
          element: '.tour-label-product',
          title: 'Product report',
          content: 'Click on a specific product to see more reports.',
        },
      ],
    });
    tourNewReports.init();
    tourNewReports.start();
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't even compile and I get the following error:

```
Error: Error invoking _class3. Check the inner error for details.
 ------------------------------------------------
Inner Error:
Message: key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?
Inner Error Stack:
Error: key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?
```

I've also tried skipping the injection and just using `const tourNewReports = new Tour({`, but I get this error:

```
bootstrap_tour__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.Tour is not a constructor
    at _class3.startTour
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, please specify: typescript or ecma6? Are you using webpack?

Comment: I took a look and the issue appears to be the way that Tour is exported. Please try again doing:
import Tour from 'bootstrap-tour'
without the brackets.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to inject it, instead of using it directly.

Comment: either register that class with the DI (and use this.tour instead of new this.tour) or use new Tour in the constructor (and use this.tour instead of new this.tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments from Cristián Ormazábal, avrahamcool and Rabah G helped me with this issue.  The simplest solution was:

```
import Tour from 'bootstrap-tour';
```

Then, use it directly as follows:

```
startTour() {
  const tourNewReports = new Tour({
    steps: [
      {
        element: '#tour-btn-menu',
        title: 'New reports!',
        content: 'Check out new reports!',
      },
      {
        element: '.tour-label-product',
        title: 'Product report',
        content: 'Click on a specific product to see more reports.',
      },
    ],
  });
  tourNewReports.init();
  tourNewReports.start();
}
```

However, in the end, it appears that bootstrap-tour may be an abandoned repo.  It's currently incompatible with Bootstrap 3.4.1 (the latest v3 release), and therefore useless to me.  If someone still wants to use it, there are a couple workarounds and an alternate forked repo posted here:

https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/issues/723